# Value on model and table keeps turning up as null

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a table called `PCRStatusLog` with a column called `PromoteDate`.  This column is fed a date where data from an excel sheet was sent from staging to the primary database.  It's a new column, hasn't been used yet so for most records it is null, but we need to display the data of this column to our webapp.  Most of the logic to do so already exists and the models are ADO.NET entity models generated from EF Designer From Data Base in Visual Studio.

In the table, `PromoteDate` is `DATETIME` and nullable (SQL Server) and the model for the table looks like this:

```
    public partial class PCRStatusLog
    {
        // ... list of fields and properties
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PromoteDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And was generated code, not entered manually.  There's nothing special about that class, it's only a list of getters/setters that map to a table, a typical simple entity model.

Here is where it is used (I didn't write most of this code, I only added changes concerning the PromoteDate):

```
public List<PCRTracking> GetPCRTrackingDetails()
        {

            //...
            List<PCRTracking> pcrDetails = (from bulk in providerMasterContext.BULK_UPLOADS
                                            join ps in providerMasterContext.PROCESSSTATUS on bulk.ProcessStatusID equals ps.ProcessStatusID
                                            join p in providerMasterContext.PLANs on bulk.PlanCode equals p.PlanCode
                                            where bulk.CreateDate > compDateTime
                                            orderby bulk.BulkUploadID descending
                                            select new PCRTracking
                                            {
                                                FileID = bulk.BulkUploadID,
                                                FileName = bulk.BulkUploadActualFileName,
                                                PlanName = p.PlanCode,
                                                FileStatus = string.Empty,
                                                RecordsSubmitted = 0,
                                                RecordsFailed = 0,
                                                ValidationStatusReports = string.Empty,
                                                ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                                                Submitter = bulk.SubmissionByID,
                                                SubmitterName = bulk.SubmissionByName,
                                                SubmitDate = (DateTime)bulk.SubmissionDateTime
                                            }).ToList<PCRTracking>();

            foreach (PCRTracking item in pcrDetails)
            {
                var promoteDateQuery = (from psl in providerMasterContext.PCRStatusLogs
                                        where psl.BulkUploadID == item.FileID
                                        select psl).FirstOrDefault();

                item.PromoteDate = promoteDateQuery.PromoteDate;
                //... rest of the code doesn't make use of PromoteDate
```

All of the other fields in PCRTracking object work fine, but PromoteDate keeps coming up as null, even on the one record that I manually edited to have a date.

Even here, where I examine the object returned by querying the one record I *know* has a date under promote date, it turns out null:

```
// from the Main method of a test console project
            var providerMasterContext = new BulkPCRDAL().providerMasterContext;
            var query =(from psl in providerMasterContext.PCRStatusLogs
               where psl.BulkUploadID == 43
               select psl).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach(var prop in query.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(query));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

It grabs all the properties on the object, and everything looks right, and matches whats in the database, except this one PromoteDate property.

Am I missing something?

Note that everything else in this model works, all other fields display data from the db, this one field is the only one that won't work.

Comment: I'd start here: Change `var promoteDateQuery = (from psl in providerMasterContext.PCRStatusLogs
                                        where psl.BulkUploadID == item.FileID
                                        select psl).FirstOrDefault();` to.... (continued in next comment for clarity)

Comment: `var promoteDateQuery = (from psl in providerMasterContext.PCRStatusLogs).ToList();`

Comment: This is a temp change just to test. Look at the results in `promoteDateQuery` and see if your known instance exists and if it has a date.

Comment: You could even do: `var promoteDateQuery = (from psl in providerMasterContext.PCRStatusLogs where psl.PromoteDate != null).ToList();`

Comment: basically, force the return you want and see if you get it. Just a way to troubleshoot and narrow down where the problem is.